# Newbie connecting to mssql from php script

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a ton of experience connecting to MySQL, but I'm attempting to connect to a SQL Server for the first time.

I've been given an IP address, server name, and a port. I've tried every combination I can think of for the server string to make the connection, but nothing appears to be working:

"127.0.0.1:1443\servername"

"127.0.0.1,1443\servername"

"servername\127.0.0.1:1443"

"servername\127.0.0.1,1443"

etc...

All fail.

I guess I'm asking for the correct formatting of the server parameter string to connect to MS SQL from a php script.

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '1433';
$server_name = 'servername';    
$server = "$ip,$port\servername"; // <-- this is the line I need help with
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$con = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password) 
or die('Could not connect to the server!');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using linux

```
$con = mssql_connect($server_name.":".$port,$username,$password);
```

or on windows

```
$con = mssql_connect($server_name.",".$port,$username,$password);
```

to connect mssql server

Comment: Wish I had seen this before I spent 4 hours debugging this. Why does PHP on Windows use a comma?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '1433';
$server_name = 'servername';    
$server = "$ip.":".$port";
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$con = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password) 
or die('Could not connect to the server!');
```

This should work

Comment: The client gave me bad credentials. I didn't want to throw it back his guy unless I confirmed they were bad. Thanks!